How to render Pdf File inside Nextjs App Securly
how to render pdf file in nextjs app and pervent user to downloding this pdf from google tools.
If the using of  server-side rendering then deliver this render to the client component without sending the url of file is right ...is there any Example of explantation please ?
i try to develop this idea inside this code but it give me an error :
Fetching error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/dynamic/route.ts:30:32)
import { decryptURL } from '@/lib/secure';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import { PDFDocumentProxy } from 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api';


// Configure PDF.js worker source
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
export async function GET(req: Request) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
    const url = searchParams.get('url');
    const filepath = decryptURL(url as string);
    
    
    try {
        const response = await fetch(filepath);
        if (response.ok) {
            const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
            const pdfData = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            const pdfDoc = await pdfjs.getDocument({ data: pdfData }).promise;
        

            // Render the PDF document
            const renderedPages = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.numPages; i++) {
                const page = await pdfDoc.getPage(i);
                const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

      
                if(canvasContext){
                  canvas.height = viewport.height;
                  canvas.width = viewport.width;
                  await page.render({ canvasContext, viewport }).promise;
                  const pageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // Convert each page to base64 image
                  renderedPages.push(pageDataUrl);
                }else{
                  console.log("canvas context is null")
                }
                
            }

            // Construct a response containing rendered pages
            return new Response(JSON.stringify(renderedPages), {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fetching error:", error);
        return new Response("Bad fetching", { status: 500 });
    }
}


